# Google-app script: Send mail from secondary mailadress

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps-script, google-apps

I have the following situation:

- xxx@gmail.com (gmail login)
- xxx@company.be (mails are standard send from this mailadress)

So far so good.
I use a script in google apps to send a newsletter to all my contacts.

The script always uses the xxx@gmail.com adress instead of xxx@company.be

This is the specific part of the script:

> var emailYourAddr   = Session.getUser().getEmail();

Does anybody know how to change the script so the mails will be sent from the standard mailadress?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Use Amazon SES to send email. Very easy to do this and much more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to first configure the company mail with gmail and then Use the company email as alias to send to send mail where the from field will show company email.

Below two links might be helpful to you.

http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=22370

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_gmailapp#getAliases

Comment: Thank you!
The first link had I already found and was applied.
The second link was the missing link!